# Docker-Compose (Apache + SSL, PHP, Mysql)

Tags: docker, apache, ssl

I'm having difficulty using docker-compose which enables Apache with SSL, PHP, Mysql.
In my attempts, PHP is even running, but Apache's was unable to get the security certificate recognized. Is there an error inside the Dockerfile and that's why SSL don't work correctly?

PS: I'm on macOS Sonoma.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./../:/var/www/html/
      - ./ssl/localhost.crt:/etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
      - ./ssl/localhost.key:/etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key
      - ./servername.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/servername.conf
    command: ["apache2-foreground"]
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  # MySQL 8.0
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: teste_clayton
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    command: mysqld --sql_mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
    volumes:
      - ./../docker-mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  # MongoDB
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  # OpenSearch (Elasticsearch)
  opensearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
    volumes:
      - ./../docker-elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    mem_limit: 2g

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN pecl install redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN echo "session.save_handler = redis" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "session.save_path = tcp://localhost:6379" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# RUN echo "upload_max_filesize = 500M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/upload.ini;
# RUN echo "post_max_size = 520M;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/upload.ini;
# RUN echo "memory_limit = -1;" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory_limit.ini

COPY ./custom_hosts /etc/hosts

RUN mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl

COPY ./ssl/localhost.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
COPY ./ssl/localhost.key /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key

RUN a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod ssl

RUN service apache2 restart

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

servername.conf

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/var/run/httpd/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>

  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
mkdir -p ~/Sites/docker-compose/ssl;
cd ~/Sites/docker-compose/ssl;

openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048;
openssl req -new -x509 -key localhost.key -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost;
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain localhost.crt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use already created docker images, like [webdevops/php-apache](https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache.html) . I can confirm that it works with SSL.

Under section **Apache layout** you can see directories and paths where you need to add cert files using volumes